# Flutter: How to pick image and mark the image as "picked" with a check mark in the gallery?

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

I am building a social app using flutter. I am using image_picker package to pick image and videos from gallery but I also want to mark all the images in the gallery which are already picked with a "check mark", so that user knows while picking more images which ones are already picked by him. Can someone suggest how to implement this?

This should be a feature of the image_picker package btw.